# ubuntu 18.04 -> 20.04 ; internet fails after sleep

Tags: networking, suspend, dns

I have upgraded my laptop from 18.04 to 20.04.
Every thing works fine - wifi up and running, internet browsing ok.

But after a sleep period - even if Wifi is on, and despite IP address has been correctly set up; internet does not work : the command `ping google.com` that worked before the sleep, no long works. And so for other internet access.

I have implemented this workaround :
https://letsfoss.com/fix-wifi-not-working-after-suspend-in-ubuntu/

But it does not help in my case.

-- update of 11th of August --
It turns out that the name resolution service does not respond to some request.

After sleep wakeup:

- ping 192.168.0.x  is working properly (so Wifi is indeed setup for
  local network)
- ping google.com : fails (that is working fine before the sleep period).
- resolvectl query google.com : works.

When doing an `strace` on the faulty ping :

```
...
177 connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53),sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.53")}, 16) = 0
178 poll([{fd=5, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=5,revents=POLLOUT}])
179 sendmmsg(5, [{msg_hdr={msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\37\205\1 \0\1\0\0\0\0\0\1\6google\3com\0\0\1\0\1\0\0)\4"..., iov_len=39}], ms
180 poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 0 (Timeout)
...
```

Ping invokes on socket 5 the local service name resolution (port 53 at local address 127.0.0.53) for getting the real IP address of google.com, but this socket does not answer. The service `systemd-resolv` is still running - this is verified via 2 means (systemctl systemd-resolv provides a status saying it is still active, and if I manually update `/etc/resolv.conf` by inserting `nameserver 8.8.8.8`) then name resolution succeeds.

But still, what can cause such issue on my installation ?

Answer (score 1):

run this script ...

```
#!/bin/bash
# program to check wifi and reset if not running
  
#dns server 
IPTEST=1.1.1.1
  
iwconfig=/sbin/iwconfig
lspci=/usr/bin/lspci

#find 802 wireless device id
DEVICE=`$iwconfig 2>/dev/null | egrep 802 | awk ' {print $1}'`

#get PCI bus wireless #  
WLNUM=`$lspci | grep -i wireless | awk ' {print $1}'`
  
#get driver to unload
WLMOD=`$lspci -vv -s $WLNUM | grep -i "kernel driver" | awk ' {print $5}'`
  
  
#print out stats      
echo "IP is: $IPTEST"
echo "DEVICE is: $DEVICE"
echo "PCI DEV NUM is $WLNUM"
echo "PCI DRIVER is $WLMOD"
ping -c 1 $IPTEST

read -n 1 -p "Proceed ? " ANS

if [[ "$ANS" =~ [^yY] ]]; then 
    exit 0
fi
  
echo ""
if ping -c 1 $IPTEST >/dev/null 2>&1 ; 
then
    echo "$IPTEST 1 ok"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Ping failed"

    echo "stopping wifi "
    sudo nmcli radio wifi off
    echo "sleeping for 3..."
    sleep 3

    echo "unloading $DEVICE"
    sudo nmcli device disconnect $DEVICE
    echo "sleeping for 3..."
    sleep 3


    echo "unloading $WLMOD ..."
    sudo modprobe -r $WLMOD
    echo "sleeping for 3..."
    sleep 3

    echo "reloading $WLMOD"
    sudo modprobe $WLMOD
    echo "sleeping for 3..."
    sleep 3

    echo "reloading $DEVICE"
    sudo nmcli device connect $DEVICE
    echo "sleeping for 10..."
    sleep 10

    echo "stop wifi "
    sudo nmcli radio wifi off
    echo "sleeping for 3..."
    sleep 3
    
    echo "starting wifi"
    sudo nmcli radio wifi on
    echo "sleeping for 3..."
    sleep 5

    echo "test ping again ..."
    ping -c 1 $IPTEST
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, it helps me to go a bit further in the investigation - I have updated my question accordingly.